# Does 'async' in Javascript actually create an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I run the following code:

```
let asyncFunction = async () => {
    console.log("hello world")
    return Promise.resolve("resolution");
}
let returnValue = asyncFunction();
console.log(returnValue)
```

This logs "hello world" and then "Promise {  }". My questions are:

1) The fact that "hello world" gets logged first indicates that making asyncFunction an async function does not make it run asynchronously. If it were run asynchronously, it would get pushed to the execution queue and not run until the main function got popped from the stack. ie "console.log(returnValue)" would get run first. Am I correct about this, that adding 'async' does not make the function actually run asynchronously?

2) If it is the case that asyncFunction does not run asynchronously, then in the line "let returnValue = asyncFunction();", asyncFunction should run before its return value is assigned to returnValue. The fact that returnValue contains "Promise {  }" indicates that asyncFunction has not been run yet, which would be consistent with asyncFunction being asynchronous. If I remove the 'async' keyword from the definition of asyncFunction, it returns "hello world" and then "Promise { 'resolution' }". So, does this imply that using async DOES make a function asynchronous?

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually `async` should be optional here and change nothing, that it logs `Promise { }` and `Promise { 'resolution' }` is surprising.

Comment: @JonasWilms that's the main thing that I'm trying to understand: why it does that. I would have expected returnValue to be "Promise { 'resolution' }". So if I remove 'async', it does return "Promise { 'resolution' }", AND I just noticed that if I keep async but do "return 'resolution';" instead of "return Promise.resolve("resolution");" it also returns "Promise { 'resolution' }". Do you know why returning the string itself like that makes the difference from returning the promise resolved with the string?

Comment: Ah okay, it seems as if it already shows the value when `promise.resolve()`, and not if the romise resolved already. It is like `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(42))`

Comment: @JonasWilms I think you're right about `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(42))`. Although if I do

`let a = Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(42))
console.log(a)`

it does log 42. BUT, if I do

`let a = new Promise(res => {
    res(1)
})
let b = new Promise(res => {
    res(a)
})
console.log(b)`

it logs Promise{ <pending> }. Do you know why those two would be different?

Answer (score 3):

> Am I correct about this, that adding 'async' does not make the function actually run asynchronously?

`async` functions actually execute *synchronously*, line-by-line from the start, until something asynchronous is encountered, like an `await` of a Promise. This is identical to the behavior of constructing a Promise manually - the Promise constructor will initially run synchronously, not asynchronously, though it's free to make asynchronous calls:

```js
const prom = new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('inside constructor');
  resolve();
});
console.log('prom has been constructed');
prom.then(() => {
  console.log('inside then');
});
console.log('end of main thread');
```

An `async` function will always return a `Promise` that resolves to the whatever was `return`ed by the function (or `undefined`). See how calling `.then` on your call of the `async` function also results in the `.then` executing at the very end:

```js
let asyncFunction = async () => {
    console.log("hello world")
    return Promise.resolve("resolution");
}
let returnValue = asyncFunction();
console.log('returnValue', returnValue);
returnValue.then(() => {
  console.log('inside then');
});
console.log('end of main thread');
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your explanation confirms what I thought I understood about async functions not being asynchronous, ie. it answers question 1. And as you pointed out, the callback to a '.then' is run asynchronously.
I'm interested in what you said about an async function returning a promise that resolves to whatever was returned by the async function. Because I notice that if I change the line "return Promise.resolve("resolution");" to "return "resolution";" then returnValue is Promise{ "resolution" } instead of Promise{ <pending> }. Do you know what the...

Comment: ...difference is between an async function returning a value (where the async function then returns a promise resolved with that value) and returning an actual resolved promise?

Comment: If you return something wrapped in `Promise.resolve`, that promise has to resolve first before the promise returned by the async function resolves, so you see `Pending`. Shouldn't make any difference for consumers of async functions, though

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding the mechanism behind `async`.  The function invocations as you describe them are synchronous.  The `async` keyword just means that the return value of a function will always be wrapped in a Promise and that you can use the `await` keyword to wait for Promises within the function's execution.

Comment: Hi @zero298, thanks for your reply. This ^^ is what I understood async function to do. What I'm still not understanding is why when an async function returns "Promise.resolve('resolution')" that gets logged as "Promise{ <pending> }" whereas if the async function returns "resolution", that gets logged as "Promise{ 'resolution' }". Do you know?